# How to upload pcap file over 1GB on Github?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to upload network capture files in pcap format to Github, but I can't. Files are more than 1 GB in size. I tried using Git LFS, but without success. Is there any other way I can use to send these files? Are there other ways I can use to send these files? I thank the help of all!

Comment: In addition to what @Kim said: Git is for diffing, branching, merging and exchanging branches which are chains of commits. Github is not a file hosting, it's a hosting for Git repositories. Most probably you not gonna store history (chains of commits) of these pcap files so our advice is: don't use Git for them, don't use Github to exchange them.

Comment: Instead compress them using `xz -9` (currently a compressor with the best ratio albeit very slow) and upload to a file hosting.

Comment: Thank you for your help . These files are part of a project and that's why I would like to put them on github. But I thank you all in advance for your help.